# plot.circular in R: changing circle labels

Tags: r, plot

Relatively new to R...

I want to control the text labels plot.circular (part of the circular package) displays around the circle.  The defaults for data with degrees units are 0, 90, 180, 270.  I want those revised to +/-180, -90, 0, 90.

To produce the default labels, here's sample code with circular package installed.

```
library`(circular)
x = circular(rvonmises(20, circular(0), 1)*180/pi-180, units="degrees")
plot(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is based on the `axis` command, like in the "classic" `plot`.

```
library(circular)
x = circular(rvonmises(20, circular(0), 1)*180/pi-180, units="degrees")

plot(x, axes=FALSE, ticks=FALSE)
axis.circular(at=circular(seq(0, 2*pi-pi/2, pi/2)), 
              labels=c("+/-180", "-90", "0", "90"))
```

[image]